# How to make dropbox items unselectable?

Tags: angularjs

I have this html element:

```
  <select class="form-control" ng-model="current.data.sites" ng-options="item.Id as item.Description for item in current.lookups.siteReg | filterByIdArray: current.data.sites">
  <option value="">--Data--</option>
```

When I open the dropbox I want the items to be displayed but I want to make the unselectable.

Any idea how can I make items in dropbox unselectable?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set disabled on the option tag. If you want to make all options disabled then you have to use ng-repeat rather than ng-options.

```
  <select class="form-control" >
     <option value="">--Data--</option>
     <option ng-repeat="item in current.lookups.siteReg | filterByIdArray: current.data.sites" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the ["disabled" flag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_disabled.asp) on the options.